# Name Error in python from function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, iteration, nameerror

I have a code here that uses functions to draw outputs. I keep getting "prompt" is not defined but isn't it already stated in the function filterer?
[enter image description here][1]

```
def menu():
    print ("[1] Compute Area of a Circle")
    print ("[2] Compute Perimeter of a Rectangle")
    print ("[3] Compute Volume of a Cone")
    print ("[4] Compute Slope of a Straight Line")
    print ("[5] Exit")

    #Determining the input of the user    
    choice = filterer("Choose from the menu:")

#function for the filter
def filterer(prompt):
    while True:
       choice = float(input(prompt))
       if choice > 5 or choice < 1:
          print ("Must input integer between 1 and 5. Input again")
        elif choice.is_integer == False:
          print ("Must put an integer. Input again.")
        else:
          return prompt

filterer(choice)
```

Comment: `prompt` is defined within the function definition, but not outside it; namely, it's not defined for the line `filterer(prompt)`

Comment: When you call `filterer(prompt)` on the last line, what is the value of `prompt`? You haven't defined it anywhere.

Comment: but isn't using "filterer(prompt)" the way to call the function value? I need the value since it will be used for other functions.

Comment: Didn't I defined it in the line "else: return prompt"?

Comment: should I use a different word instead of prompt?

Comment: You're getting the error when you are trying to invoke. You're supposed to pass in a value. At that scope you don't have 'prompt' defined.

Answer (score 1):

@Hamms and @stybl both answered this in the comments, however, just to be clear, you need to change

```
filterer(prompt)
```

into

```
filterer("do some amazing thing or something")
```

Except with the quote you want to use as a prompt instead of "do some amazing thing or something."

The key to this is to think about the scope of the code.  `filterer(prompt)` assumes prompt is defined by the time it's called.  But you're calling it without ever defining a prompt.  You could define the prompt if you wanted to, for example,

```
prompt = "do something super groovy"
filterer(prompt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out the main issue, which is that you're trying to reference a variable (`prompt`) which doesn't exist in that scope.

That said, I don't think you want to call `filterer` twice, and I don't think you want it to return the prompt, but rather the choice made. Also, your integer testing wasn't right.

Here's full working code:

```
def filterer(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            choice = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            # Value couldn't be parsed as an integer
            print("You must enter an integer. Try again.")
        else:
            # Value was successfully parsed
            if choice > 5 or choice < 1:
                print("Must input integer between 1 and 5. Input again")
            else:
                return choice  # <-- changed from prompt

def menu():
    print("[1] Compute Area of a Circle")
    print("[2] Compute Perimeter of a Rectangle")
    print("[3] Compute Volume of a Cone")
    print("[4] Compute Slope of a Straight Line")
    print("[5] Exit")

    # Determining the input of the user    
    choice = filterer("Choose from the menu: ")

    print("You chose: {}".format(choice))

menu()
```

Comment: Instead of `return choice`, maybe he was looking for a recursive call: `return filterer(prompt)`

Comment: @BrettBeatty Why do you think that? That would just lead to seeing the menu over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

prompt is defined within the scope of the function filterer, so it cannot be accessed outside the function. The line:

```
filterer(prompt)
```

Should be changed to something like:

```
foo=filterer(bar)
```

The variable bar has to be defined before doing this.